# Чем отличаются "пере-" и "об-" "рабатывающий"?

Tags: значения

То есть, почему один завод называется "нефтеперерабатывающим", а другой- "деревообрабатывающим".  Может быть, просто от благозвучности?  Есть ли конкретная разница между "перерабатывать" и "обрабатывать"?

Честно говоря, я знаю, что процессы на таких заводах отличаются.  На нефтеперерабатывающем заводе, любую внутримолекулярную связь можно ломать, а на деревообрабатывающем заводе, цель разрывать несколько связей, чтобы разделить виды вещества. Итак, я хочу узнать, что эти разные основания слов действительно описывают процессы.

Спасибо.

Comment: Нефть перерабатывается и из нее получаются другие вещества, не нефть. А дерево обрабатывается, и получается всё равно дерево, но например доски вместо стволов.  Но это конечно очень условные различия.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Пере-рабатывать** - превращать во что-то другое, что либо совсем не имеет никаких намёков на изначальный ресурс, либо эта связь неважна и неакцентируется. Из нефти делают, например, пластмассу. То, что она сделана из нефти, для потребителя совершенно не важно. Поэтому нефть **пере**рабатывают.

**Об-рабатывать** - производить какие-то операции, которые не приведут к потери какой-то (пусть визуальной) связи с первоначальным материалом. Дерево **об**рабатывают и делают из него мебель, при этом то, что мебель из дерева - делает её дороже, изначальный ресурс подчёркивается, он остаётся одним из основных элементов. В тоже время дерево **пере**рабатывают в бумагу - её связь с деревом не важна для потребителя.

Comment: А вот, почему, при поиске целлюлозно-бумажного завода на снимках Усть-Илимска в интернете, является только деревообрабатывающий завод?

Comment: Просто нет в базе данных :) http://wikimapia.org/#lang=ru&lat=58.044094&lon=102.821732&z=14&m=b&show=/27523727/ru/УИ-ДЗ

Comment: Если честно - не знаю. Более подходящее название ему - деревоперерабатывающий. Тут может быть два варианта - либо это уже устоявшееся название, либо потому, что продукция - Древесно стружечная плита, а не бумага, т.е. по сути изделия из дерева.

Answer (score 10):

Наверно разница в степени сохранения исходного сырья. Нефть полностью разделяется на составляющие, т.е. идет переработка сырья. А вот древесина приобретает необходимую форму и обрабатывается дополнительными веществами. Получается, что дерево, проходя завод, сохраняется как материал. Оно обрабатывается.

Comment: Есть предлог этого вопроса.  Есть тоже "целлюлозно-бумажны комбинат".  Дерево входит, а целлюлоз и бумага выходят.  Не то же самое вещество.   И есть "деревообрабатывающий завод".  Можно назвать деревообрабатывающий завод целлюлозно-бумажным комбинатом?  Взглядьте на снимку из спутника города Усть-Илимска.  Там есть целлюлозно-бумажный комбинат, а только деревообрабатывающий завод является.

Comment: @JohnS думаю, это ошибка в карте. Здравый смысл говорит, что деревоОБрабатывающий завод выпускает обработанное дерево, но не  превращённое во что-то другое. В Усть-Илимске много древесного сырья, я думаю, там есть и то, и то. И остатки деревообработки идут на ЦБК.

Comment: в Усть-Илимске таких заводов два, один деревообрабатывающий, выпускает ДСП (древесно-стружечную плиту), другой - ЦБК, выпускает целлюлозу (надеюсь и бумагу) http://wikimapia.org/#lang=ru&lat=58.044094&lon=102.821732&z=14&m=b&show=/27523727/ru/УИ-ДЗ

Comment: Спасибо.  ДЗ, может быть, значит "древесинный завод"?  Кроме этого, все сейчас ясно.

Answer (score 8):

Это разные процессы, разные значения, дело не в благозвучии. Даже дерево может перерабатываться и обрабатываться. Например, когда из него делают бумагу, то это переработка (перерабатывается). А когда дерево, например, сушится, пропитывается чем-то, когда его шлифуют, строгают, обрабатывают паром и т.п. - это обработка (обрабатывается).